# SCIP optimizer parameter

Tags: scip, parameter

I am looking for the name of the parameter in SCIP, which instructs the solver NOT to transform the $Abs(x)$, $Max(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$ functions into a set a linear constraints (using additional binaries).

A second question is, how can I pass to the solver the constraint $Max(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$ using the Osil format?

Comment: Would you elaborate more on what you mean by `instructs the solver NOT to transform the Abs, Max functions into a set of linear constraints`? Do you mean is throughout the solving process?

Comment: It is possible that whenever SCIP sees an expression like $Max(x_1,x_2,..) \ge  a$, it transforms it into an equivalent set of linear constraints by introducing new binaries.  I would like to be able to instruct SCIP not to do so, but to treat it as a nonlinear expression.

Comment: I found here (https://dev.ampl.com/solvers/scip/options.html) a parameter acc:abs  that does the job, but I cannot find the equivalent in SCIP. It is also not clear to me if this option instructs AMPL to do the reformulation or SCIP.

Comment: thanks. As far as I know SCIP can deal with some non-convex function by using non-linear cons handler. Also, there is no way to add $Max$ function directly into SCIP. You need to linearize $Min / Max$ function by an appropriate way, then workaround with that in SCIP.

Comment: GAMS and AMPL can pass such constraints to SCIP directly through their interfaces to the solver. However, SCIP does not accept Osil, nl input files generated by GAMS resp. AMPL, containing the Min/Max keyword.